# why regex leaves

Tags: python, regex

i was trying to learn regex. i came across this code in tutorial with this code from sentdex youtube channel.

```
import re

ExampleLine = "prices xom 91.43-91.44/vz50-50.01/s 7.23-7.24"
regex = re.findall(r"\w{1,3}\s?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,2}-\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,2}", ExampleLine)
print(regex)
```

prints:

```
['xom 91.43-91.44', 'vz50-50.01', 's 7.23-7.24']
```

i get the matching patterns. what i fail to inderstand is why the prices in the ExampleLine is not getting matched? how is that getting skipped?

thanks in advance..

Comment: because `price` isn't followed by  an ipaddress or number or whatever

Comment: Why do you believe that "prices" should be matched?

Comment: i had the one of the many basic concept of reg ex wrong. i thought it will go through the entire string looking for match starting from the first char in the string. i was wrong. i now see that it will match based on reg ex we write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is

```
\w{1,3}\s?\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,2}-\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,2}
```

It means match between 1 to 3 characters from the set `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

```
\w ==> [A-Za-z0-9_]
```

This set does not contain any spaces(even it would have contained, there wouldn't have been any effect at least for this example).

So it is matching

```
xom 91.43-91.44
```

and leaving out `prices`.

You can visualize it **[here](https://regex101.com/r/pK8hY9/1)**